# Is there any possible way to give share programs not code in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am going make some programs in Google Apps Script for a non-profit organization. I don't want give them my code. Is there any possible way to give them programs not code. Actually, I don't want anyone to see or change my code.

And I also don't want to use Web App. My script will access their contacts and Spreadsheets.

Comment: Could you be more specific what is the scenario or workflow where you want to use this program?

Comment: there gonna be couple programs. for example one is updating their organizations contacts though a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to investigate Libraries.  You can put the segments of the code you want to protect into a library, and then give them code (macros, scripts, whatever) that just calls that library - they will be able to see the code you gave, but not the library.  However I don't know how "foolproof" this is if someone was really determined to dig.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries?hl=en

Comment: I am unable to find the way to make libraries. Can you help with that?